# draw barplot with different color with labels, using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to draw bar plot with different colors. The data is time series data, looks like:

```
date          volume         label
2015-02-16    102              1 
2015-02-17    112              1 
2015-02-18    152              2 
2015-02-19    132              1 
2015-02-20    122              1 
2015-02-21    92               3
```

I want to draw this time series data as bar plot using ggplot. The difficulty parts are that,

1) I want to draw black color, with label = 1, red color with label = 2 and blue color with label = 3

2) I want to plot the label "1", "2", "3" on the top of each daily bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For coloring you can use `scale_fill_manual`, for labels you can use `text` (use the `vjust` argument to adjust where the labels appear on the bar).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(date, volume, fill=factor(label))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=label), color="white", vjust=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=levels(dat$label), values=c('black', 'red', 'blue'))
```

[image]